# Deploy SSRS report to remote server over VPN from different domains

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

After connecting to the VPN, in Visual Studio on my local machine, I set the target server to

http://[RemoteServer]/ReportServer

but I get the error

```
"The specified report server URL could not be found"
```

I can RDP to the remote server, but my login is DOMAIN-B\MyUser. On my local machine, my login is DOMAIN-A\MyUser.

On RDP, I am able to verify that Reporting Services are running and the target URL is correct.

How can I deploy an SSRS project from Visual Studio on my local machine to a remote server, on a different domain, over a VPN connection?

More broadly, how does Reporting Services authenticate report deployments? I would imagine Visual Studio would require some credentials when trying to deploy to the Target Server, just like when you connect to a database in SQL Server, but I am never prompted on my local machine, and I don't know how to set that up on the remote server.

Comment: Try adding some windows credential details. Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager

Answer (score 0):

Try:

http://[RemoteServer].[Domain].local/ReportServer